# How to resolve conflicts that are showing in Team synchronizer in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, subclipse

Im trying to merge all changes in branch to trunk folder using svn in eclipse.

In team synchronizing window when i clicked on conflict file it is showing

```
<<<<<<< .working
```

and

```
>>>>>>> .merge-right.r303
```

And im not able to commit. I do not understand how to resolve it.

I just need to merge all changes to trunk

Please let me know, how i can resolve these conflicts

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you resolve this conflict? Because they are too many?

With Subclipse, there is a [recent bug](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1046&dsMessageId=2662264):

> - If Subclipse is able to merge the changes automatically, everything works fine (I can approve the auto-merge and check in).
> - If Subclipse cannot auto-merge two files, the user is asked to either launch a graphical conflict resolution editor, or to mark the files as conflicted and deal with it later. If one launches the conflict editor immediately, there's no problem.
> - **If one has the conflicts marked and deals with it later, that's when the encoding problem occurs**.
>
> The "Edit Conflicts" editor will display the "working" file to the left, and the "merge-right" file on the right. The "working" file on the left looks OK, with all special characters intact (for example "ü").
>   The "merge-right" file on the right however is displayed with ISO-8859-1 encoding (project default), so all special characters are "garbled". The "ü" character is displayed as "Ã" for example.

Have you any encoding issue causing conflicts?

Comment: i donot know abt "Edit conflicts", So i just leave the conflict files just commit remaining files to the trunk and after that copy that files from branch folder to trunk folder manually :( i think that i did some thing wrong when im not able to commit conflict files. bt with ur answer i understand that is a bug in subclipse.. Thank you Vonc

Comment: This bug has to do with character encoding -- I doubt this is your issue.